# Firestore security rule, how to check length in the security rule

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need to check the length of the key, but 'key.length' doesn't work.

```
//DOESN'T WORK
match /queue/{key} {
  allow read: if key.length > 12;
}
```

I have tried and the '==' operator works well, it returns true on case an exact string match.

```
//WORKS WELL
match /queue/{key} {
  allow read: if key == "foobar";
}
```

Please let me know, what I am doing wrong!

Comment: try : `key.size `

Comment: @fatemehyadollahzadeh you should write an answer based on your comment. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#size

Answer (score 2):

you should try `.size` instead of .length

```
match /queue/{key} {
  allow read: if key.size> 12;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`key.size()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#size) instead.